# Codeception doesn't read from env specified

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, codeception

I'm trying to configure my Codeception in Laravel to use credentials from my `env.testing`. However, it doesn't seem to work. Here're the related files:

```
# unit.suite.yml

class_name: UnitTester
params:
  - .env.testing
modules:
  enabled:
    - Asserts
    - \Helper\Unit
    - Laravel5
    - Db:
        dsn: "mysql:host=%DB_HOST%:%DB_PORT%;dbname=%DB_DATABASE%"
        user: 'root'
        password: ''
        dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
        populate: true
        cleanup: true
        populator: 'mysql -u %DB_USERNAME% -h %DB_HOST% %DB_DATABASE% < tests/_data/dump.sql'


# .env.testing

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I keep on getting error as if I'm supplying empty value for `DB_HOST`. I've verified that it's actually working by using hard coded value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the testing configuration file in the same directory?

Comment: Is the path to .env.testing correct?